# jQuery .addClass() on scroll event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I am facing an issue with addClass() on a scroll event. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li id="pop">Home</li>
        <li>Programs</li>
        <li>Replay</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 250px;
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 }

 .sidebar ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
 padding-left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 }

 .sidebar li {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 80px;
  }

  .active {
  width: 140px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 25px;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {

   var st = $(this).scrollTop(); 
   if( st > 500 ) {
   $("#pop").addClass("active"); 
   } else {
   $("#pop").removeClass("active"); 
   }
  }); 
 });
```

I have also tried to use toggleClass() without any success. I can't figure out what what is preventing it from working.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't work with jquery, but is $(window) not referencing the Window object? If you only want to scroll inside the div, than you may need to change that part.

Comment: Try outputting to console and seen if the st variable is getting anything!

Comment: You can replace all your if logic with `$('#top').toggleClass('active', st > 500);`

Comment: using toggleClass() on each <li> with an id didn't work either for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this :

**Css :**

Remove this :

```
 .sidebar li {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 80px;
  }
```

And add :

```
.normal {
  font-size: 13px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  width: 80px;
  }

  .active {
  width: 140px;
  background-color:orange;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  }
```

**Html :**

Add class `normal` to `li`s

```
<ul>
  <li id="pop" class="normal">Home</li>
  <li class="normal">Programs</li>
  <li class="normal">Replay</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on("scroll",function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) 

            $("#pop").removeClass("normal").addClass("active");

        else 

            $("#pop").removeClass("active").addClass("normal");


    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                height: 2500px;
            }
            .sidebar div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 250px;
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 }

 .sidebar ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
 padding-left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 }

  .normal {
  font-size: 13px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  width: 80px;
  }

  .active {
  width: 140px;
  background-color:orange;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
       <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li id="pop" class="normal">Home</li>
        <li class="normal">Programs</li>
        <li class="normal">Replay</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).on("scroll",function() {

                if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) 

                    $("#pop").removeClass("normal").addClass("active");

                else 

                    $("#pop").removeClass("active").addClass("normal");


            })
        })

        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, replacing with class="normal" solved the problem. Does this mean that to toggleClass() or addClass() on an element it should already have a specific class already defined?

Comment: @Dounia,in your problem,yes.you must add class normal.if my post help you,mark it please,

Answer (score -1):

Be more specific with your css:

```
<style>
  div.sidebar li.active {
  width: 140px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 25px;
  }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o266wh3r/1/